# A maximal clique containing exactly n vertices and have a maximum total edge weight

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

In the weighted graph (edge-weighted), I look for possibilities for finding a maximal clique containing exactly `n` vertices and have a maximum weight. From the documentation, "For weighted graphs, `FindClique` gives a set of vertices with a maximum sum of vertex weights." 
I transform from edge weight to vertex weight, but it works a while. Any suggestions on how to do it?

```
v = 100;
e = v*3;
g = RandomGraph[{v, e}];
gw = AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 
   EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{1, 5}, e]];
gf = AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 
   VertexWeight -> Total[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[gw]]];
FindClique[gf, 10] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: You should separate questions which are not related. 1. and 2. are completely unrelated, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You should be aware that `FindClique[g,{n}]` does not find a clique with `n` vertices. It finds a *maximal* clique with `n` vertices. This is why `FindClique[CompleteGraph[5], {4}]` returns nothing. None of the size-4 cliques are maximal.

Comment: My typo, I look for maximal clique

Comment: It sounds like a very unusual requirement.

Comment: Might not be very efficient but this could be cast as an ILP problem.